# Subsets whose size is a power of $2$

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

A set with $n$ elements contains $2^n$ subsets. What if we restrict to subsets whose size is a power of two? Does this quantity behave differently asymptotically? I.e. what is the asymptotic behaviour of:

$$f(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log{n}\rfloor}\binom{n}{2^k}$$

Comment: Looks like OEIS doesn't know this one.  As a first guess though: each value $2^k$ is associated with a polynomial of order $2^k$, and so for a given $n$ we can say that $f$ behaves like a polynomial of order $\frac{n}{2} < \lfloor 2^{\lg n} \rfloor \le n$, so it looks exponential.

Comment: As any subset of $\{1,\ldots\lfloor n/2\rfloor\}$ can be extended to size a power of two by adding elements from $\{\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1,\ldots n\}$  (using the fact that there is always a power of $2$ bewtween $x$ and $2x$) , we have $2^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\le f(n)\le 2^n$

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the comments, it's exponential.  Perhaps the best way to describe the asymptotics of such a sequence are to examine the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of $\frac{1}{n}\log f(n)$.

Let's first notice that $$\max_{k \leq \log n} \binom{n}{2^k} \leq f(n) \leq \log n \max_{k \leq \log n} \binom{n}{2^k}.$$

This implies that $$\frac{1}{n} \log f(n) = \frac{1}{n}\max_{k \leq \log n} \log \binom{n}{2^k} + o(1)$$ as $n \to \infty$.  Note that this maximum is at most $\log \binom{n}{|n/2|} / n$ which approaches $\log(2)$; moreover, this maximum is achieved along powers of $2$ implying that the $\limsup$ is indeed $2^n$.

The lower bound isn't much harder: observe that for $n$ in the range $[2^m, 2^{m+1}]$, the maximum is smallest at $n = 3\cdot 2^{m-1}$.  We're thus interested in the quantity $$\lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{1}{3\cdot 2^{m-1}} \log\binom{3 \cdot 2^{m-1}}{2^{m-1}}\,.$$  Applying Stirling's formula shows that the limit along this sequence is $\log(3) - \frac{2}{3}\log(2).$  This shows that $$\limsup_{n \to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\log f(n) = \log(2) \approx .693,\qquad \liminf_{n \to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \log f(n) = \log(3) - \frac{2}{3}\log(2) \approx .637$$

Comment: You're right, I was confused there. Where you say "observe", I agree that this is true, since at this point the maximum switches from $\binom n{2^{m-1}}$ to $\binom n{2^m}$ and the former is decreasing whereas the latter is increasing -- but is it obvious how to prove this?

Comment: I don't have a good and easy argument for it, but I'm certain that there must be a nice way to see this; one way to prove it in the limit is to apply Stirling's formula  $\log(\binom{xn}{n/2})/(xn)$ and note that the resulting function is decreasing for $x \in [1,2]$; you can do similar stuff with the other power of $2$ to show that that's increasing, so the minimum is when the two are equal.